# Sum values across different sheets/files based on a match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of names, 1 excel file with 10 sheets in it. 
I am using pandas with conda 2.7.

The columns in the file (same column names):

1. name
2. col1
3. col2
4. value

Each sheet has names which are a subset of the previously mentioned list of names.

What I need to do is output 1 file with 1 sheet. Each sheet needs to be structured like:

list of names | value_sheet1 | value_sheet2 | ... | value_sheet10 | summed_values

I need to step through each sheet, and pull out value associated with the name on the condition: **[list of names] = [name]**

For example:

```
list of names = ["Jack","Jill","Doe"]
```

**sheet1:**

```
name | col1 | col2 | value
Jack |   .. |   .. |  10
Doe  |  ..  |  ..  |  15
```

**sheet2:**

```
name | col1 | col2 | value
Jill |   .. |   .. |  10
Doe  |  ..  |  ..  |  15
```

**output_sheet:**

```
name | value_sheet1 | value_sheet2 | ... | summed_value
Jack |     10       |      0       |  .. |    10
Doe  |     15       |      15      |  .. |    30
Jill |      0       |      10      |  .. |    10
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update More sheets

```
l=[df1,df2]
l=[y.set_index('name').add_prefix('sheet'+str(x+1)+'_') for x,y in enumerate(l)]
df=pd.concat(l,axis=1,sort=False)
df['New']=df.filter(like='value').sum(1)
df
Out[485]: 
      sheet1_value  sheet2_value   New
Jack         10.0          NaN  10.0
Doe          15.0         15.0  30.0
Jill          NaN         10.0  10.0
```

How to create the `list` of dfs

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(fn)


d={name:xl.parse(name) for name in xl.sheet_names}
l=d.values()
```

Comment: Hmm, if I need to step through each sheet? (There are 10 sheets). 
I am using a for loop to step through the sheet names and then read in each sheet within the for loop.

Comment: Sorry, I am still a bit confused. Could you list out where the for loop comes into play here? I do not get where df1 and df2 come from. (I just began working with pandas a couple of days ago). I appreciate your answers.

Comment: @lazycamper ok so you do not know how to read the different sheet into pandas ?

Comment: No, I have that part working.
for sheet in sheet_names:
      df5 = pd.read_excel(xls, str(sheet))

Comment: @lazycamper i have update where the list of dfs come from:-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190471/discussion-between-lazycamper-and-wen-ben).